# Genitiv von „McDonald’s“ u.ä. im Deutschen?

Tags: grammatical-case, genitive, apostrophe

Die Fast-Food-Kette McDonald’s benutzt einen englischen Genitiv mit Apostroph, der im Deutschen üblicherweise nicht gesetzt wird. Wie aber verhält es sich, wenn ich diesen Begriff im Genitiv in einem Satz verwende?

Sage ich „McDonald’s Hamburger kostet x €.“ oder „McDonald’s’ Hamburger kostet x €.“?

Ich weiß: Der zweite Satz sieht irgendwie blöd aus, aber wäre er nicht grammatikalisch korrekt? Denn es heißt zum Beispiel auch „Andreas’ Auto ist schmutzig.“, wenn es das Auto von Andrea**s** (und *nicht* das von Andrea) ist.

Comment: An sich hätte die englische Sprache dasselbe Problem, ignoriert es aber einfach (auch dort besetzt der Name schon die Genitivform, trotzdem schreibt da keiner "McDonald's's turnover this year..."). Warum sollten wir uns also diese Sorgen machen?

Comment: @tofro Auch in der englischen Sprache dürfte es nach einem s am Ende nur ein Apostroph ohne zusätzliches s sein. ("The girls' ...", nicht "The girls's ...") Abgesehen davon schert man sich sonst auch nicht um die Regeln der Ursprungssprache eines Wortes. Es werden gnadenlos die Regeln der deutschen Sprache angewandt. Insofern ist die Schreibweise in englischer Sprache ohnehin ohne Relevanz.

Comment: „The girls’“ bezieht sich aber auf den englischen Genitiv Plural. Insofern wird man auch nie im Englischen auf „The girls’s“ stoßen, da es grammatikalisch einfach falsch ist und es keinen Anlass gibt, dies anders zu sehen.

Answer (score 3):

Bei Namen, die auf -s enden, wird im Genitiv normalerweise ein Apostroph angehängt. Wenn man diese Regel im vorliegenden Fall anwendet, käme wie schon vorgeschlagen ein zweiter Apostroph hinzu:

> McDonald’s’ Hamburger kostet x €

Da das sehr merkwürdig aussieht, wird das in der Praxis kaum jemand machen, sondern man wird sich mit "von" behelfen:

> Der Hamburger von McDonald’s kostet x €

Comment: Zum ersten Teil der Antwort: volle Zustimmung. Aber als Alternative würde ich eher eine Konstruktion bevorzugen, die ohne Genitiv auskommt: "Bei McDonald's kostet der Hamburger € Euro".